# PHP website does not work, and nothing logged in the error log

Tags: php, apache

I have a problem with PHP. There is an error that I have never encountered before. The home.php, which is the main page of my site, cannot be viewed. And there is nothing in error log. After  there is an inclusion of a php page (a class that is a part of my API). Till that line the holl HTML (javascript and css inclusions) are echoed from php and successfully rendered in browser, but after  the php kind of stops suddenly. When I delete that line(php page inclusion line), website works, but before,  this inclusion didn't make any problem for me. I removed the code parts which after them I encountered this problem, but nothing works.

I am using Apache2, PHP5 with Ubuntu 11.10.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: And what kind of error output do you get, have you checked the error log for php? Also it would be nice if you could show the source of the file you are trying to include.

Comment: can you please display home.php file startup php code??

Comment: Could you describe you problem a little more detailed? What error did you get? Can you show some of the code that you are trying to execute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first hints would be to check the following:

- In your script set **ini_set('display_errors', '1');** and **error_reporting(E_ALL);** to display all errors.
- Turn on the php error log and check it for errors.
- run **php -l home.php** on the command line to check your php file for syntax errors.
- Check Apache's error log, sometimes error messages go there.

If nothing helps use a debbugger like **XDebug** to see where the script terminates, or alternative insert statements like **die("here");** and move them around in your code, to see which parts of your scripts are passed.

Greetings and good luck.